# Entity Framework TPH: how to map foreign keys to DB columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api, table-per-hierarchy, tph

I am using Table-Per-Hierarchy pattern (same DB table for all derived classes), like this:

Base class:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

A few derived classes, some of them having Address, like this:

```
public class Student : Person
{
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher : Person
{
    public virtual  Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately, when the database is created, a new column is created for every address foreign key like this: `Address_Id`, `Address_Id1` ... `Address_IdN`

It is possible to overcome it by explicitly adding foreign key to every class using Address like this:

```
public class XXX : Person
{
    [Column("AddressId")]
    public virtual int AddressId { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("AddressId")]
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }

}
```

However, this solution requires having `AddressId` property in the classes which is undesirable. It cannot be hidden declaring as private or protected, because table mapped property must be public.

I thought of using fluent API like this:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
            .HasOptional(s => s.Address)
            .WithRequired(a => (a.Person as Student));
```

or

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
                    .HasRequired(a => a.Person)
                    .WithOptional(s => (s as Student).Address);
```

but there is a problem with casting between the base and the derived class. Now I am stuck…